# .prefetch() and .cache() not speeding up tf.data.Dataset pipeline

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a very big dataset of high resolution images so I am training over small chunks using keras.fit.
For loading chunks in memory I have a generator function which generates a tuple of tensors of variable size which I pass to tf.data.Dataset to create a data pipeline.

```
def extract_XY(list_idx):
    read_images(list_idx)
    append to list X
    process, extract patch and convert to tensor X (?,100,100,3)  #? means variable size mini-batch
    Y = f(X)  
    return X,Y

for i in range(epochs):
    for j in range(chunks):
        x,y = extract_XY(list_idx) #list_idx changes in each loop
        data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X,Y)).batch(64).cache().prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
        model.fit(data,epochs=2,verbose=1)
```

My training with keras fit works but still slow I see no speed up using .cache() or .prefetch()
Can anyone help me understand if I am using them correctly in my case.
I can't use tf.data.Dataset.from_generator option as my generator doesn't yield a sequence.

Can I make my data-pipeline more efficient i.e., loading next chunk while model is training? any suggestions would be helpful?
Does using multiprocessing=True in Keras.fit() will help more? or tf.data.Dataset is already taking care of I/O bottleneck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `keras.utils.Sequence` to write your generator, then use `model.fit_generator()` with `multiprocessing=True`.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal I have already tried that but this option leads to memory error. Many people are facing this issue and the usual suggestion on forums is to build I/O pipeline with tf.data.